# Decoding error while querying using Python cx_Oracle library

Tags: python, oracle, encoding, utf-8, cx-oracle

I am getting decoding error while using pd.read_sql.I am querying Oracle DB , and using cx_oracle library.

I have tried passing the encoding parameter in the Oracle Connection String as below.

cx_oracle.connect(user=user_name, password=pwd, dsn=dsn_tns,encoding="UTF-8")

The encoding options i have tried and error i am getting everytime pd.read_sql runs is as below:

1. With encoding = 'UTF-8', error is utf-8' codec can't decode byte
   0xc3 in position 34: unexpected end of data
2. With encoding="UTF-8",nencoding="UTF-8", error is utf-8' codec can't
   decode byte 0xc3 in position 34: unexpected end of data With
3. With encoding="UTF-16", nencoding="UTF-16", error is ORA-29275: partial
   multibyte character

The NLS_CHARACTERSET is AL32UTF8.

Anyone who has faced this issue and resolved, please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Which Python version? What does your code look like? What happens if you *remove* any encoding parameters? Python 3 strings are Unicode so there shouldn't be any need for encoding. Using `UTF16` when the database field is UTF8 only guarantees an error

Comment: What does the *input* look like and where did it come? It's quite possible it already contains invalid characters. If you loaded some single-byte text from a file and tried to pass it as-is to the database, all bytes with values>127 are invalid in the UTF8 encoding

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Python version is 3.7. Removing encoding parameters is giving UTF-8 error.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: The input was loaded from an existing DB to the Oracle DB. It was not loaded from file. these are some sample data.

Comment: Can you read that data with any client tool? Can you read the *row* that causes the problem in Python? Have you tried connecting *without* trying to force the encoding? *Post your code*

Comment: yes, we can read the data with client tool. No, we cannot read the row,  causing problem, in Python, Without encoding it gives error. This is what i am using to connect ......                                                               
oracle.connect(user=user_name, password=pwd, dsn=dsn_tns,encoding="UTF-8").  Once connected i am using pandas.read_sql("query","Connectionstring"). It fails at pandas.read_sql.

Comment: this is some of the sample data : "惠州市", "Филиа" , "plynárenský"

Comment: I'm closing to vote this question because after 2 hours there's still no code that could reproduce the error *in the question itself*. Post the *complete* information in the question, not as tidbits in comments. This is like pulling teeth

Comment: BTW that error means the data is *not* UTF8. So you'd have to post a `CREATE TABLE` statement and `INSERT` clauses that create a table with a field in that specific encoding, with test data, that people can use to fully reproduce the problem. Perhaps the problem is a hard-coded non-UTF8 encoding in ORACLE HOME?

Comment: The version of cx_oracle matters. Test it with version 8, which uses UTF-8 by default for `.connect()`. Do not use the NLS environment variables to set the character set. Your post is missing the query and the datatypes of the columns that exhibit this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you have corrupt data try something like suggested in the cx_Oracle doc [Querying Corrupt Data](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#codecerror):

```
def OutputTypeHandler(cursor, name, defaultType, size, precision, scale):
    if defaultType == cx_Oracle.STRING:
        return cursor.var(defaultType, size, arraysize=cursor.arraysize,
                encodingErrors="replace")

cursor.outputtypehandler = OutputTypeHandler

cursor.execute("select column1, column2 from SomeTableWithBadData")
```

Comment: i dont think it is corrupt data, but rather data in non english characters. Like this "惠州市", "Филиа" , "plynárenský".   So i should not be replacing them. i should be able to read them as is.

Comment: @ashasasidharan this page you're reading is UTF8 and yet you didn't have to do *anything* to post those non-English characters.

Comment: The documentation link suggests passing `encoding_errors="replace"`. This failed with  `"error":"'encoding_errors' is an invalid keyword argument for this function` when I tried it. Switching to camelCase `encodingErrors="replace"` as shown above fixed the error

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  The camel case name was deprecated a while back so new code with the latest driver should use the underscore.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to determine the character set that your server is set to:

```
SELECT value
FROM nls_database_parameters
WHERE parameter in ('NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET');
```

Then set the `encoding` and `nencoding` parameters of `.connect()` to match client to the server. ( `AL32UTF8` on server matches `UTF-8` on client)

If your columns are of types `nvarchar`, `nclob` etc. then you need to use the `nencoding` parameter as well. But you did not post the column datatypes nor your query.

```
cx_oracle.connect(user=user_name, password=pwd, dsn=dsn_tns, encoding="UTF-8", nencoding="UTF-8")
```

If your server really is `AL32UTF8` and cx_oracle still gives you a decode error with `encoding` set to `UTF-8`, then as the other answer says, you have corrupt data. Test by querying a different, smaller set of rows.